# Determine Which Hyper-V VMSwitch(s) Are Connected to Ethernet

Tags: networking, ethernet, hyper-v

We will be installing Hyper-V VMs onto laptops where others may have already set up an external VMSwitch connected to Ethernet. If so, we would like to use that switch; if not, we will create our own. Gathering external switches, though, doesn't discriminate between, say, Ethernet or WiFi adapters. We can't find how to tell which switches are connected to which physical ethernet adapters. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you done any research? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you mean with a script or manually?  You can manually look in Hyper-V Manager in the Virtual Switch Manager.   The cmdlet get-vmswitch will give you a list of your virtual switches also

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear: I want to do this in a script.